# Counter top refrigeration of dairy creamer carton?

Tags: equipment, milk, freshness

I've set up a coffee/drink bar complete with coffee, espresso machine, various sweeteners, stirring sticks, teas, liquors, etc.

However the one thing missing at the bar is the creamer: we use half-and-half which requires refrigeration. So every time I make a drink that uses creamer I need to make a walk to the kitchen refrigerator to get the creamer.

[image]

I've thought of a few ways to solve this problem, but they all fall short for various reasons:

- Use those small 1-tsp sized creamer cups which aren't refrigerated - way more costly per oz than a carton of half-n-half and opening several of them when making drinks for the family is a hassle
- Use powdered creamer - ech!
- Install a mini fridge at the bar

The last option is the closest to what I'd like, but the smallest mini-fridge at my local Home Depot is still large enough to fit ~10-15 of these cartons which seems like overkill. Also they don't fit on top of the counter, so I'd need to remove a cabinet from under the counter, and hiring a carpenter just to get my creamer closer to my coffee also seems quite overkill.

Has anyone here with the same issue as me come up with an elegant solution?

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! I've closed this as a duplicate for now because I think the answers on the other question offer many approaches addressing a similar problem. If you think it's not a duplicate, please reply to this comment or custom flag the question. :)

Comment: Specifically the recommendation to look for tiny fridges. The USB ones in my experience don't work well, but there are plug-in ~10L fridges for about $50 out there that work beautifully and don't kill your counter space.